# Disabling triggers to insert record in a table may result delay, how to manage it?

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am working on integration project that deal with manufacturing database, my project is using C# and SQL Server, I use a stored procedure to insert.

The main table for transactions has already big number of triggers that are used to do many functions including updating other tables.

I can not insert into this table only if I disable the triggers, now I am doing that using C# that ask another stored procedure `uspDisableAllTrigger` to do this.

The question is should I merge the two stored procedures (disable and insert stored procedures) into one stored procedure, or I keep it two stored procedures and call them from C# code?

Mainly I care about performance and delay (as delay may result inconsistency of data and the updating triggers will be disabled for some time)

Comment: This sounds like the *real* problem is your triggers. Triggers should be as minimal as possible, and if you have lots of triggers on a single table, then they are likely *not* minimal and very likely should not be triggers.

Comment: Yes, it is and it is legacy database and fed from many systems so can not be changed, we can just extend the functionality

Comment: If it's a legacy database, why is stuff still being inserted into it then? Legacy applications infer that it's there for old data and processing, and is being replaced; so the new application should be the thing with the new data. If it's still being used to current data, it's not really a legacy application.

Comment: Yes, my description is wrong maybe but it is a database that is not changeable but extendable.

Comment: Not changeable meaning not modifiable ( risky to modify) and tables are chained to each other ( dependencies )

Comment: *"risky to modify"* This is why development and testing environments exist, as it's not a risk on a environment you can easily roll back. Clearly the problem you want to avoid it for "normal" operation to not run the triggers, while your process doesn't; if you have 2 simultaneous calls, one from you and one which is a "normal" operation, while the triggers are disabled, both won't use the triggers. This is why the triggers are the problem, as it seems that either they shouldn't be there, or you *should* be using the triggers in your process.

Comment: Or, perhaps, the triggers should be handling your process differently; in which case the definition of the trigger needs updating to cater for your process.

Comment: No one without an intimate knowledge of your system and how it works can offer any real suggestions for you. Disabling triggers is an extreme risk. You should be talking with the team that manages your actions and this system - not strangers.

Comment: The problem with disabling triggers is it's a *global* action. It affects all connections, not just yours. Which means you can only safely disable them if you're the only one accessing the database.